# Run two commands in START command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, terminal

I want to start maven and then close this opened window. So far, i got this:

```
start /high "C:\Program Files\apache-maven\bin\mvn.cmd -f <dir> && exit" > "log-something.txt"
```

However, it just prints out terminal and no output. Is this correct syntax to run two programs?

Comment: What is the `/hight` option? do you mean `/high`? Anyway, at first, try to put an empty pair of quotes like `start "" /high ...`; then try `start "" /high "cmd /C <program-dir> <params> && exit"`...

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Thx i will try this

Comment: It stil only opens new cmd window at current location. I dont know if it makes any difference, but my program dir includes spaces

Comment: Oops, I just found a typo in my suggestion too, it should have been `start "" /high cmd /C "<program-dir> <params> && exit"` (note the quotes); or you try this: `start "" /HIGH cmd /C "<program-dir>" <params> ^&^& exit`, or: `start "" /HIGH cmd /C ""<program-dir>" <params> && exit"`...

Comment: It would also help were you to provide us with the actual content you're using, `<program-dir> <params>` is of no use given your previous comment.

Comment: @Compo i am trying to run Maven with parameters. I cannot share thoose parameters

Comment: You can share the command line and parameter strings, you should only have to replace occasional characters with others from the same character set, to protect any sensitive information. Unwillingness to make more of an effort to more accurately provide us with the command line with which you're having an issue, makes it considerably harder for us to diagnose it.

Comment: You're supposed to enclose filepaths which include spaces in quotation marks, `"C:\Program Files\apache-maven\bin\mvn.cmd -f <dir> && exit"` isn't the name of the executable file, `"C:\Program Files\apache-maven\bin\mvn.cmd"` is. Also as your executable file is already a [tag:batch-file], you may also want to consider using `Call`, otherwise you'll need to `Start` a `cmd.exe` instance with your correctly quoted command, executable file and parameter. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `cmd /?` to read the help information, which should better explain the use of quote characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the idea. The only thing is to fix the syntax. You add `""` in the parameters because first parameter in quotas is treated as title (and you dont want it):

```
start /high "" cmd /c ""<programDir>" -f <dir> && exit" > "log-something.txt"
```

Notice that here it is okay to use double double quotas. Dont use single quotas